# Where can I find Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1 included?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

The recently published [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) to VS 2015 Update 1 seems to require VS 2015 RTM to first be installed.

Is there a more convenient distribution of VS 2015 that includes Update 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Update 1:

The community edition is available here:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409

And if you have a MSDN, you can get it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads/?#searchTerm=Visual%20Studio%202015%20with%20Update%201&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0